# How to plot(object), when <object> is user defined?

Tags: r, plot, package

I have written a function that draws some plots, and returns a list, similar in style to the following format:

```
myfun <- function(x, y){
    plot(x, y)
    points(x+1, y+1)
    abline(v=x[1])
    mylist <- list(x=x,y=y,line=x[1])
    return(mylist)
}
```

This works fine. However, in R, one generally plots from functions in the following way:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
lin <- lm(x~y)
plot(lin)
```

i.e., one creates an object using the function, then uses **plot(object)** to get the plot. How can I set up my function to behave in this way? I've had a look at a few guides to writing R packages (including hadley's), but I couldn't find reference to this problem.

I would like to create this functionality so I can upload what I've created to CRAN or R-Forge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own S3 class for it (
R provides a lot of object oriented systems (S3, S4, R5, R.oo, ...), see also: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html):

```
# create an object with an own class
lin = list(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
class(lin) = "mylin"

# overload plotting function
plot.mylin = function(l) { 
  plot(l$x, l$y)
  points(l$x+1, l$y+1, col=2)
  abline(v=l$x[1])
}

# run it
plot(lin)
```

Comment: This is perfect. This box states "Avoid comments like 'Thanks'". I'm new to SE, so I'm not sure how to thank you! I have ticked that you've answered my question, and I will upvote it when I am able.